# SharePoint 2013 Online. Priority rules - Content Organizer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Somebody know what is exactly the meaning of the priority in the rules content organizer in sharepoint 2013 online.
what is the best value for this property?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The content organizer checks the metadata of an uploaded document against the content organizer rules to determine where the document should be routed.

The priority simply determines the order in which the rules are evaluated. This allows you to tell it to check a certain rule before checking another. This is important because if the content organizer determines that the document meets the requirements put forth by a rule, it will stop evaluating any remaining rules and move the document to the appropriate location.

When you want a rule to be evaluated before some other rule, you increase its priority by setting it to a lower number. Higher priority rules (which have lower numbers) will be checked before lower priority rules (which have higher numbers).